# running function more than one times returns "error: Can't set headers after they are sent"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, electron

Program runs as it should until I try to use the function once again and it returns the **error: Can't set headers after they are sent**.

I'm creating this app to familiarize myself with nodejs and javascript and I've been reading about the error and it seems to be an issue when sending more than one response to a request. I started using **res.setHeader** before knowing this, but I read that **res.header** could avoid this problem, it didn't solve it but I kept it.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="youtube2music.css">
    <title>
        Youtube2Music
    </title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="cabeza">
        <h1>
            Youtube 2 Music
        </h1>
        <p>
            just paste your link below and download your song.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="down-part">
        <input id="myUrl" class='myUrl-input'>
        </input>
        <button type="button" class="download_button">
        Download
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src='youtube2music.js'></script>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var urlinput = document.querySelector('.myUrl-input'); // gets url inputbox
var button = document.querySelector('.download_button'); // gets download button

button.addEventListener('click', () => {

  console.log(urlinput.value); // prints in console the url
  sendUrl(urlinput.value); // sends url to function to start the request

});

// function to make requst
function sendUrl(URL){

  window.location.href = `http://localhost:4000/?URL=${URL}`; // makes the video request to nodejs server
}
```

index.js < node file:

```
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var sfn;
appi.use(cors());
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

function createWindow(){
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width:800, height:600});
  win.loadFile('index.html');
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)

appi.listen(4000, () => {
 console.log('server at port 4000');
});

appi.get('/',(req,res)=>{
 var URL = req.query.URL;
 ytdl.getInfo(URL, function(err,info){
   if(err) throw err;
   var songTitle = info.title;
   sfn = filenamify(songTitle);
   eventEmitter.emit('name_ready');
 });

 var startDownload = function(){
  let stream = ytdl(URL, {
   quality: 'highestaudio',
  });
  res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + sfn + '.mp3');
  res.header('Content-type', 'audio/mpeg');
  proc = new ffmpeg({source: stream})
  proc.withAudioCodec('libmp3lame').toFormat('mp3').output(res).run();
 }
 eventEmitter.on('name_ready', startDownload);
})
```

as it is works for the first input but asking for another output results in error, why is it really returning this error and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your current setup:

1. Try not to use event emitter for signaling events within an HTTP request, it wasn't made for this.
2. With HTTP requests, try not to use global variables for data received during the request, when two requests come in at the same time, they may get confused and get sent the wrong data.

```
appi.listen(4000, () => {
 console.log('server at port 4000');
});

appi.get('/', (req,res)=> {
  const { URL } = req.query;
  ytdl.getInfo(URL, (err,info) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    const songTitle = info.title;
    const sfn = filenamify(songTitle);
    let stream = ytdl(URL, {
      quality: 'highestaudio',
    });
    res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + sfn + '.mp3');
    res.set('Content-type', 'audio/mpeg');
    const proc = new ffmpeg({source: stream})
    proc.withAudioCodec('libmp3lame').toFormat('mp3').output(res).run();
  });
})
```

Comment: I didn't think of using `const` thank you, could you explain why is `res.set` used in this case?

Comment: `res.set` is the documented version of `res.header`: [res.set](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set)